# NodeJS program memory usage won't go down

Tags: javascript, node.js, io.js

I was writing a nodejs program but it has some problems, I created an issue in the iojs github but the guys said that it's likely a problem in my code and I should try posting it here.

I'm new to javascript and server-side javascript.

This is a simplified version of my real code that is way bigger.
I tried searching everywhere for a solution for this, tried not using event emitter and everything even tried manually nulling almost everything that would not be used anymore but it won't help at all.

This small snippet "leak" the same way my original code does.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download: these three scripts

   - socket.js: https : //gist.github.com/dumpsters/11dab119e996b802a824)
   - client.js: https : //gist.github.com/dumpsters/17566cce2777470218e4)
   - server.js: https : //gist.github.com/dumpsters/860bac40048db45e0424)
2. Execute server.js
3. Execute client.js
4. Let client.js run for a while while checking server.js memory usage in the title bar
5. Close client.js
6. Check server.js memory usage

server.js memory usage will either stay the same or even increase and won't ever go down.

Tried with latest stable iojs version and latest nightly version, also tried with stable nodejs.

Any clue on why this happens?

Comment: How many requests have you tried to make? If you are seeing only 'minor' memory increase (i.e. initial 100MB to 300MB) that may be caused by the v8 optimiser generating optimised code, thus consuming more RAM. It should eventually stabilise. If you are seeing huge increase (i.e. 100MB to 2GB) then yes, there might be a problem.

Comment: Also related about how to perform memory leak analysis in Node.js - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2779#issuecomment-91209967 and following posts that lead to resolution.

Comment: Here's the gif of the usage in my real project:
http://i.imgur.com/c0LADWM.gif

Here's the gif of the usage in my test snippet:
http://i.imgur.com/sggrFky.gif

both won't go down even when all the connections are closed, is this intended to be this way?


I left the client.js running over night and when I woke up in the morning the server was frozen, it's like it wasn't listening anymore and the RAM usage was 130mb.